# ¿Cómo usar alias en Vala?

Tags: gtk, vala

Resulta que estoy utilizando los namespace Posyx y GLib, pero al querer imprimir por pantalla un mensaje como por ejemplo:
`stdout.printf("mensaje");` me salta el siguiente error: 
`` error: `stderr' is an ambiguous reference between `GLib.stderr' and `Posix.stderr' ``

He leido que tengo que utilizar alias para solventar el problema, pero no sé aplicarlo aún para que no me siga lanzando los errores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema no es que tengas que usar un alias, sino que ambos namespaces tienen su propio método `stdout.printf` referencialo desde el namespace de Glib para poder imprimir un mensaje en pantalla:

```
GLib.stdout.printf ("mensaje");
```

Tambien lo puedes usar desde el namespace de `posix`:

```
Posix.stdout.printf ("mensaje");
```

Comment: Ahhh, creo que la sabía pero la pasé por alto. Otra alternatica que encontré es:
global::Posix.system("comando"); //En mi caso tenía que utilizar esta función.
Gracias.

Comment: eso es para ejecutar comandos, tu pregunta especifica solo para imprimir mensajes

Comment: Bueno, pero a lo que yo iba era a que otra forma era esa, en el caso de imprimir sería:
global::Posix.stdout.printf ("mensaje");